# Webpage for creating roadmaps?

Tags: web-apps, project-management, time-management

Is there some sort of webpage where I can create a visual roadmap/timeline of what I have to do? This would help me a lot at work since currently I do everything on paper each day, and things get lost.

I am looking for something similar to this:
[image]

The key features I look for:

- Simplicity - No learning curve
- Freedom - be able and edit all fields
- Online - so I can access from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

A more common name for what you're describing would probably be the [Gantt chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart). Similarly, it may be easier to look for online timeline management or project management software. That noted, here are a few options to consider:

- Use [Google spreadsheets](http://www.hellotecho.com/how-to-create-a-simple-gantt-chart-with-google-sheets). You can also find lots of prebuilt Gantt templates online too.
- Some dedicated platforms worth considering: [Wrike](https://www.wrike.com/), [AceProject](http://www.aceproject.com/), and [Tom's Planner](http://www.tomsplanner.com/). All three have free basic options. Many more options open up if you're willing to pay.
- Use [Microsoft Excel](http://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, though the problem with spreadsheets is that they are too hard for this task (at least to create the visualization and simplistic interface).

Comment: From the above, Tom's Planner looks the most promising. Still a bit too many clicks for simple things..

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there will be a few hoops to jump through with most platforms for this. Some of the paid options, like Zoho Projects, can be a little more intuitive and streamlined though.